# Is it possible to make a Windows Server 2016 VDI template?

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2016, vdi

I was looking for this but could not find any answer (nor a question like that to be honest :).

Anyway the questions is, is it possible to create a VDI collection from a template with Windows Server 2016 OS installed? I did try it both in the wizard and Powershell when trying to create a collection from a sysprep'd VM with WS2016 installed but each time got an error about template being not compatible. I would let it go but apparently "some guy" claims it is possible since the 2016 version and it requires certain Powershell magic. Could anyone confirm this?

btw, I'm using Windows Server 2016 Remote Desktop Services

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this with a template based on Windows Server 2016 OS.
You must use a client operating system if you want to make a template out of it. Best option is to use Windows 10.

There is also a new feature in Windows Server 2016 - the Server Based Personal Desktops (or Personal Session Desktops) which is a hybrid of the two, the RD Session Host and RD Virtualization Host based deployment. The result is VDI scenario sans a cient OS (practically based on Server 2016 OS).